# Postgres analyze takes time after upgrade 11.12 to 13.4

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

Issue:Analyze running for hours

I kept maintenance worker memory as 1 gb and maintenance workers as 4.DB Size is 40 GB
We upgraded postgres from 11.12 to 13.4.
Post upgrade, i am running analyze as below statement and i am seeing this job runs for hours.
(4 hours still running) .
Any input for this unusual long hours.

Note:
Command i used->  `**VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE,parallel 4)**`

Tracking via below statement:
select * from pg_stat_progress_analyze,From this table,I can see per second 250 blocks are scanned

Comment: Tune the statement. If you need help, show the statement, the table and index definitions and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output

Comment: 1) How did you upgrade? 2) Why not just run `ANALYZE` by itself? I'm not seeing a need for the `VACUUM`. 3) Is there other activity on this database? Add answers as update to your question.